# What should I do to get database response from this vertx code

Tags: vert.x

This is the method used for database connection and obtain results:

```
public Future<String> getDatabaseUsers(JDBCClient client) {
    return Future.future(pHandler -> {
        client.getConnection(res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                SQLConnection con = res.result();
                con.query("select u.id, u.name from users u", rHandler -> {
                    String data;
                    if (rHandler.succeeded()) {
                        data = Json.encode(rHandler.result().getResults());
                    } else {
                        data = "Database execution error";
                    }
                    con.close();
                    pHandler.complete(data);
                });
            } else {
                pHandler.complete("Cannot connect to database");
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This is the caller method:

```
private void handleRequest(RoutingContext routingContext, JDBCClient client,
        Handler<List<String>> resultHandler) {
    routingContext.vertx().<String>executeBlocking(pHandler -> {
        pHandler.complete(getDatabaseUsers(client).result());
    }, ar -> {
        List<String> responses = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ar.succeeded()) {
            responses.add(ar.result());
            System.out.println(Json.encode(responses)); // Null here
        }
        resultHandler.handle(responses);
    });
}
```

The resultHandler object is used to add more responses from other processes; but this is not the problem actually.

And this is the endpoint:

```
router.get("/db").handler(ctx -> handleRequest(
            ctx, client, (list) -> ctx.response()
                    .putHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
                    .end(Json.encode(list))));
```

The problem with this code, is that service response is [null] and the database method is not accomplished yet.
So, what should I do to wait for database response and then send the response to the client?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this code:

1. `getDatabaseUsers` swallows errors. You probably want to do `pHandler.fail(res.failure())`; or something similar.
2. This code: `pHandler.complete(getDatabaseUsers(client).result());` is not doing what you think it's doing. `result()` doesn't block, so you complete your future with another unfishined future.

What you actually want is the reverse:

```
getDatabaseUsers(client).handle((r) -> { // This is called when the futures actually completes
    if (r.succeeded()) {
        pHandler.complete(r.result());
    }
    ...
});
```

I would really recommend going over [this guide, as it covers exactly your case](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/).